# Can there be planets with extremely strong magnetic fields?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, planets, electromagnetism

Would it be possible for a planet with surface conditions suitable for humans landing on it to have a very strong magnetic field, with field strengths on the planet's surface similar to the surface field strength of a typical kitchen magnet?

Comment: You really mean landing, it doesn't have to be habitable? Because the iron-nickel alloys planetary cores are composed of can naturally take a magnetic field, but a planet large enough to be habitable can't have cooled enough, I think.

Comment: I mean landing, in the same way we landed on the moon. With people in space suits walking around for a limited time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28magnetic_field%29) states that the strength of the magnetic field near a kitchen magnet is approximately 5 mT ($5 \times 10^{-3}$ Tesla), roughly 1,000 times as strong as Earth's magnetic field in that same kitchen. Note that this is measuring the $\mathbf{B}$ field of the magnet.

The magnitude of a magnetic field of a dipole at the planet's equator is
$$B=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{p}{r^3}$$
where $p$ is the magnetic moment, $r$ is the radius, and $\mu_0$ is a constant. We also know that the magnitude if $\mu_0$ is $4\pi\times10^{-7}$. Therefore, setting $B=5\times10^{-3}$, we have
$$5\times10^{-3}=1\times10^{-7}\frac{p}{r^3}\to p=r^3\times10^4$$
Substituting in Earth's radius, we find that the planet must have a magnetic moment of about $2.59\times10^{20}$ J/T. By contrast, if we use values for [a magnetar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar), find find $p\approx8\times10^{19}$ J/T, at most.

What happens if we shrink the radius of the planet a bit while also changing the magnetic moment to preserve magnetic field strength? Even if we shrink it by a factor of about 2.5, to make it more like Mercury, we still have a magnetic moment about the same order of magnitude incomparable to that of normal planets. If we do the reverse, making the planet bigger, then we can afford to have a bigger magnetic moment.

The one thing I haven't taken into account yet is that the mechanisms for magnetic field formation are different in magnetars and planets. [Flowers and Ruderman (1977)](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1977ApJ...215..302F&data_type=PDF_HIGH&whole_paper=YES&type=PRINTER&filetype=.pdf) present a convincing argument that the magnetic fields in magnetars are residual, formed around the time of the supernovae that created them. [Other theories](http://dspace.rri.res.in/bitstream/2289/3315/20/Chapter%203.pdf) posit that one of two other mechanisms (the battery model and the thermoelectric mechanism) are at work. The point is, these differ from the traditional [dynamo theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo_theory) that explains magnetic fields in planets and normal stars. So a planet generating a magnetic field through this method could not have as strong a magnetic field as a magnetar.<sup>1</sup>

I suppose I'll end this on an uplifting note. Bodies called [Thorne–Żytkow objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorne%E2%80%93%C5%BBytkow_object) have been studied theoretically and are being searched for experimentally. They consist of an M-type red giant or red supergiant which has collided with a neutron star; the neutron star has come to rest at its center, forming a new core. We could - and this is a stretch, but still not entirely impossible - hypothesize that you could have a gas giant planet that collides with a magnetar, which then forms something similar to a TŻO.

Is it a stretch? Yes. The resulting body would differ from TŻOs in more ways than I can explain here. Would the resulting body we a planet you could land on? No. But it's as close as you can get to having a magnetic field that powerful. Oh, and on the equator, the field would be weak, because gas giants are normally quite large. But still, it's a start.

---

<sup>Summarized from [one of my answers on Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/208693/56299).</sup>

Comment: I specifically asked about the needed size of the planet in comment. Well, indirectly but anyway. It can be much smaller than earth.

Comment: @VilleNiemi Ah, sorry, the comments hadn't loaded for me yet.